# Polling for preferred accommodation type with multiple selection and final plan generation

Tags: planning, polls

I'm looking for an online tool which would allow polling participants for their preferred accommodation types. The options would be defined by me, each type would have its capacity defined. Participants should be able to select multiple choices in the order of their preference. Morevover it should allow them to select another participant which they would prefer to be accommodated with. The tool should then generate possible plans to populate rooms in which everyone is be satisfied. Free tools preferred.

Comment: I think PollUnit meets your requirements except of the "accommodated with" feature (that's why I put this as comment). You can learn more in this tutorial: https://pollunit.com/en/tutorials/distribute_tasks
For up to 40 participants it is also free.